# Jenkins abort parallel stage

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

How can I abort one parallel job from another? I have to tasks in Jenkins pipeline that should run in parallel. As soon as task 1 is finished, task 2 should finish too. Is that possible?

```
pipeline {
  agent none
  stages {
    stage('Stage A') {
      agent {
        label "winvm01"
      }
      steps {
            script {
                stage('Stage 1') {       

                    def branches = [:]

                    branches["branch_1"] = { 
                         // do some lengthy work
                         echo "branch 1 ended"
                         // abort branch 2 here!!??
                    }

                    branches["branch_2"] = {
                        // to something that only should run while branch_1 is running
                    }
                    parallel branches
                }   
            }
       }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would work:

```
stop = false

parallel 'long': {
    sleep 20
    println "finished long process"
    stop = true
}, 'short': {
    while ( !stop ) {
        println "work"
        sleep 1
    }
    println "stopped by other branch"
}
```

You could also have branch 1 create a file at the end of the process which branch 2 will check for.

It might be a good idea to add a timeout for branch 2 in case branch 1 fails and the stop condition is never met.

Edit: forgot about the `failFast: true` flag, it's a better way of making sure the other branch stops in case the first one fails.

Comment: failFast: true only stops other stages on FAILURE though, not UNSUCCESSFUL, if I recall correctly.  It would be nice if it would work on UNSUCCESSFUL also.  The problem with your answer though is that it assumes that the job that would normally be 'println "work"' is short and can be run over and over again in a loop, waiting for stop.  I think in OP's question, branch_2 is some long running job which is supposed to be stopped when branch_1 stops.